# Django Flatpages Variables

Tags: django, django-flatpages

Is it possible to enter `{{ variable }}` into a django flatpage and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried this. The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#flatpage-templates) says that *Flatpage templates are passed a **single** context variable, flatpage, which is the flatpage object* (emphasis mine). Based on this I'd venture a guess that this is not possible. There might be workarounds (such as writing your own wrapper over the views) but I haven't see them in use.

Comment: I agree - and context processors aren't run for flatpages IIRC, so you can't inject an extra var that way either. You could write your own version of Flatpages - it's not much work - that lets you inject custom vars as well, mind you